# disable carousel button on program start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel with 3 panes. When the page is first loaded I want the left button to be disabled so the user can cycle backwards through the panes.

I have a working diableButton function:

```
function disableLButton()
{
    $(".carouselBtnLeft").attr("disabled",true);
}
```

this works fine when I call it when returning to the 1st pane.

I wan't it to also be disabled when the program first runs, I have tried simply calling the function using a firstRun bool but it does not work:

```
var firstRun = true;

if(firstRun == true)
{
    disableLButton();
    firstRun=false; 
}
```

I'm sure there is a sickeningly simple solution...

**SOLVED:**

**I added a load function to the body:**

```
<body onload="load()">
```

**Then in the load function:**

```
function load()
{
    disableLButton(true);
}
```

Comment: Just use `if (firstRun) { ... }`, you don't need the `== true`.

Comment: I have had it like that too, I was just making double sure I was doing what I wanted trying with === aswell as ==

Comment: not sure but this could be a solution `$(function(){var firstRun = true;

if(firstRun == true)
{
    disableLButton();
    firstRun=false; 
}})`

Comment: Could it have to do with placement? If you are calling the function before the element is rendered in the dom that would explain why it wouldn't work on initialization but would work after.

Comment: You should also be using `prop` instead of `attr`; the correct way of using `attr` would be `...attr('disabled', 'disabled');`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the disabled property with **prop()** instead of **attr()**

```
function disableLButton()
{
     $(".carouselBtnLeft").prop("disabled",true);
}
```

see here for API method prop()

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

The disabled attribute is considered a Boolean attribute:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2

and dont forget when removing the disabled attribute use this:

```
 $(".carouselBtnLeft").removeProp("disabled");
```

you dont set it to false since even the presence of the disabled attribute, even if it has no value will be considered true.. so use removeProp() to remove the disabled attribute